# RN Refresh parent screen after navigating back from particular screens

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, navigation, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

I have main screen A. From A it's possible to navigate B, C, D screens.
In most cases I need to refresh screen A on focus event, only A shouldn't be refreshed  when navigating back from D.

How can I implement this scenario in react native using hooks?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the react navigation lifecycle events like this

```
function Profile({ navigation }) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      // Screen was focused
      // Do something
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  return <ProfileContent />;
}
```

here is the documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle#react-navigation-lifecycle-events

Comment: I don't want to refresh screen when coming back from e.g D screen, other cases I should refresh.
Now I am adding a route parameter refreshScreen : false in D screen.
In parent screen I have this

`useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
        if (refreshScreen) fetchData() 
      return () => {
          // here I want to reset refreshScreen. navigation.setParams({refreshScreen: true});
     /// this is prompting an error when moving back to the root screen. 
//the action  SET_PARAMS with payload was not handled by any navigator.
      } }, [isConnected, refreshScreen]));`

Answer (score 0):

Something like below worked for me

**In parent**

```
const OnRefreshNeededFromChild = (isSuccess: boolean) => {
    console.log("On Returned called")
    if (isSuccess) {
        RefreshData()
    }
}


const FromParentToChild = () => {
    navigation.navigate("childpage", { OnReturn: OnRefreshNeededFromChild })
}
```

**In Child**

```
export childFunction(props: any){
    const OnRetun = props.route.params.OnReturn

    const OnButtonClick = async () => {
           .......
    //Calling the parent callback here
    OnRetun && OnRetun(true)
           ......
    }
    
}
```